# Why are my NSManagedObject subclass methods not being recognized?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I've (heavily) subclassed NSManagedObject for a project.  It worked in the original project seamlessly and without any effort.

I copied those files over to a new project, manually adding the appropriate CoreData classes to the new data model.

Unfortunately, I'm having 'issues'.  For some reason, the methods of the subclass in question are being ignored.  The exact same code between the two projects, but I'm suddenly getting an unrecognized selector issue.

```
NSFetchRequest *blockRequest=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *blockDesc=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AdBlock" 
                                           inManagedObjectContext:context];
[blockRequest setEntity:blockDesc];

AdBlock *curBlock=[adBlocks objectAtIndex:blockIndex];

adBlocks=[context executeFetchRequest:blockRequest error:nil];

for (AdBlock *block in adBlocks) {
    [block initAdBlock];//Crashes with unrecognized selector
}
```

I've checked, and the appropriate .m files got added to the compiler build phase.  The code was quite literally copy&paste and is identical between the two projects -- source works, destination doesn't.

I've noticed that I don't explicitly tell the context that it should return the subclass type, but that wasn't an issue in the old project, so why should it be an issue in the new one?

Comment: So you added the new classes to the data model but have you changed the class name to your custom class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When something like this happens to me, there's two things I try. The first thing I do is make sure I properly #imported the NSManagedObject subclass (I forget that way more often than I should), but as you said you copied and pasted, I don't think that is your problem. The second thing I try is to rebuild the NSManagedObjects by going to File>New>File then NSManagedObject Subclass then selecting the NSManagedObjects that I changed something in. I would recommend rebuilding all of them in your case. See if that works. It may not, but it's an easy place to start.

Comment: *winces*  If I rebuild them, I loose all the custom logic though!  Oh well, easier to recreate that than yell at the app to start 'just working'

Comment: After rebuilding, I'd recommend you test it before adding your custom logic back in. :)

Comment: App won't run without the custom logic -- and here I thought I was being clever, letting the class handle it's own stuff and just let the outside world know what it needed to know.  (Encapsulation ftw, right?)

Comment: Can you leave your NSManagedObject subclasses the way Xcode built them, and add your custom logic to a separate class? This would also help if you need to change the database structure later on so you don't need to add your custom logic back in.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what kind of naming convention would I use for that?  AdBlock and then AdBlockLogic?  (AdBlockWrapper?)  And yes, that's exactly what I'm thinking in terms of long-term.  (Though based on another article, I was thinking in terms of adding the 'primitive' items are transient core data variables, and using categories to extend the files)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you check your model and ensure that you've change the class names in the inspector. Otherwise, they'll return as NSManagedObjects no matter what. And use mogenerator so you don't have to worry about regenerating your classes.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is stale, but maybe someone searching will find this helpful.

I've been using categories to add additional functions to NSManagedObject subclasses.  This allows me to use the XCode command to generate the class definition without destroying any of the custom logic.  Ron mentions this in a comment on the selected answer - just thought it would be worth calling attention to as I find it's a pretty slick solution.

Comment: Yup -- that wound up being my long term solution.  Wrappers didn't exactly make sense, so I just used categories instead.